# How to save a settings record in orcharc without an admin view

Tags: c#, settings, orchardcms, updates

I have a settings record that some of the fields get maintained via the admin panel.  However, I am implementing an import for data, and need to track the last time an import occurs.  So I added that field to my settings record and created a controller that imports the data.  Now, my question is, how can I update the settings?  I have created a service, but don't know how to force orchard to save the values.

```
public class BmobileSettingsService : IBmobileSettingsService
{
    IOrchardServices _svc;
    public BmobileSettingsService(IOrchardServices svc)
    {
        _svc = svc
    }

    public BmobileSettingsPart Get()
    {
        return _svc.WorkContext.CurrentSite.As<BmobileSettingsPart>();
    }

    public void Save(BmobileSettingsPart part)
    {
        /// how do I save the data?
    }
```

Here is the code I used when using a repository:

```
public class BmobileSettingsService : IBmobileSettingsService
{
    IOrchardServices _svc;
    IRepository<BmobileSettingsPartRecord> _repository;
    public BmobileSettingsService(IOrchardServices svc,IRepository<BmobileSettingsPartRecord> repository)
    {
        _svc = svc;
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public BmobileSettingsPartRecord Get()
    {
        return _repository.Table.FirstOrDefault();
        //return _svc.WorkContext.CurrentSite.As<BmobileSettingsPart>();
    }

    public void Save(BmobileSettingsPartRecord part)
    {
        _repository.Update(part);
        _repository.Flush();
    }

}
```

Here is the call to thye service:

```
                // update the last imported date
                var rec = _bmobileSettings.Get();
                rec.LastImageSyncDate = DateTime.Today;
                _bmobileSettings.Save(rec);
```

The data just does not get persisted to the database.

Comment: Just set the properties of your part. That's it.

Comment: Setting the value does not work, as the change does not get persisted to the database, which is what I am trying to do.  This process can only be started in the Admin dashboard, but it is not a normal settings view and does not run via a handler.  I am running Orchard 1.6.1.

Comment: If it doesn't persist, it almost certainly means that the transaction got rolled back. Check your logs, you'll probably see an exception in there. Also, never use `Flush`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the question has actually been answered in the comment by Bertrand Le Roy.
I don't think you need to actually force anything.

This is an example for allowing users to register using Orchard 1.8:

```
var site = _siteService.GetSiteSettings();
var regsettings = site.As<RegistrationSettingsPart>();
regsettings.UsersCanRegister = true;
```

There is no method you need to call after setting the value.
That being said, if you have a reccord for your part you could possibly use an IRepository and call update on it. There have been bugs in older versions of Orchard where calling Update on an IRepository can force an update. However this should not be required and may merit a bug report if you're using the latest version of Orchard.

Comment: I tried using an IRepository, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: I believe as Bertrand Le Roy said that you shouldn't even have to use an IRepository (Pretty sure 1.6.1 doesn't have the bug I was thinking of). And as he's suggesting you should first check your logs. If you still have no luck, I would either try fetching the Part from CurrentSite and updating it using the IRepository. Or possibly calling create on the IRepository.